# Is there a way to check if two DOM elements are equal?

Tags: javascript, dom

It's no problem to find an element by position and the position of an element in Javascript.
But is there are general way to compare them?

The only way I could think of is comparing ids or classnames, but not all elements have ids or classnames.

Comment: What does "equal" mean in your context, then, if not same id? Is it same element type? Or same content? Please expand your question a bit...

Comment: Compare what about them? Height, background-color, z-index? What are you looking to compare.

Comment: What do you mean "equal"? Do you mean when two variables point to the same element? Or do you mean that the two elements "looks the same". If so, you then need to define what it means to "look the same": does same xy position count, does the same transparency/opacity count, same text content?

Comment: In fact, I want to compare if it is the same element two users click on. User A clicks on an element, I save position, id, class, whatever I could user to compare them. Then user B clicks on this element and I want to check if he clicked on the same element as user A.

Comment: The ID attribute should be unique for every element, so why not compare the ID?

Comment: Because not every element has an ID. Comparing the ID would be the easiest way, but what to do if the selected element doesn't have an ID? I'm searching for alternatives to checking the ID.

Answer (score 70):

In modern browsers there are two methods for comparing nodes.

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
var b = document.createElement('div');
b.isEqualNode(a); // true
```

but

```
b.isSameNode(a); //false
```

And as for IE, it's DOM elements have non-stanard attribute, [uniqueID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534704(v=vs.85).aspx).
But I can't imagine it can be useful in this case, since yes, you actually can compare two pointers.

Comment: @Andru, oh, everything changes pretty fast recent years :)))

Comment: the `isSameNode` function is deprecated, you should use `isEqualNode` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.isSameNode

Comment: @idFlood not true anymore

Comment: Is it *depreciated* or *deprecated*? We need to get our stories straight

Comment: FF seems to have stopped supporting this method quite some time ago. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_issamenode.asp

Answer (score 57):

If you want to compare two element pointers for being the same element, just use the comparison operator. This can be easily proven because

```
document.body === document.body
```

For example, if I somehow had references to two elements I didn't know:

```
if (element1 === element2) ...
```

Comment: @www139 - why is it recommend? please provide evidence

Comment: @vsync take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679762/how-to-compare-two-html-elements

Comment: @www139 - the first link has no information regarding DOM element comparison and the second link has no information regarding `==` vs `===` when comparing DOM nodes. couldn't you just give an example instead of point to irrelevant links?

Comment: @vsync I remember someone telling me somewhere that it is recommended to use === vs == . I can't find any documentation as to why it would be better for node comparison, but numerous posts on this site alone suggest that it would be a good idea. === is a strict equality test while == is a looser equality test. I don't know any more specific information. This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172506/comparing-a-dom-node-wih-a-dom-element) uses === but doesn't explain why this method is preferred, leaving me and the rest of the world wondering :)

Comment: @vsync According to this (http://appendto.com/2016/02/%3D%3D-vs.%3D%3D%3D-equality-in-javascript) == is loose comparison which ignores data type differences, i.e. '3' (string) is equal to 3 (integer) while === is a strict data type equality test.

Comment: @www139 - I am aware of the difference (after doing JS for 12 years), but I think that your first comment was out of place, since you "remember someone telling you somewhere.." without thorough understand of **why** it matters and how it related to this answer seems unprofessional. You still didn't explain why you think `===` is better than `==` in this specific case.

Comment: @vsync I think you are correct, sorry to bother people reading this discussion :)

Comment: @www139 Using === instead of == has absolutely no sense in this context. I'd suggest that you reflect this in your original comment.

Answer (score 2):

=== Operator still relevant **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode**

Even if you make changes to the DOM, === operator works fine.

```
const body = document.body; body.setAttribute("test","done"); const _body = document.body; body === _body // true.
```

:).