# How to compare two DOMs or DOM nodes in general?

Tags: javascript, dom, compare, nodes

I am using `var win1 = open.window(...); var win2 = open.window(...);` to open 2 tabs/windows in Firefox - now I want to compare the two DOMs (document object models) for similarity.
So I have got two DOMs containing a very similar page. The pages have the same HTML but executed different JavaScript files.

In general I check if HTML and CSS is the same:

```
    var html1 = win1.document.body.innerHTML;
var html2 = win2.document.body.innerHTML;
if (html1 == html2) { ... }
var css1 = win1.document.body.style.cssText
var css2 = win2.document.body.style.cssText
if (css1 == css2) { ... }
```

But comparing all DOM nodes seems to give bad results:

```
var bodyNodes1 = win1.document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
var bodyNodes2 = win2.document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

`bodyNodes1[123].innerHTML` isn't neccessary similar `bodyNodes2[123].innerHTML`

Which methods can be used to compare DOM nodes?
Do any Framework/Libraries/Scripts exist for testing pages for similarity?

I am very thankful for any hints. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is either:

isEqualNode : http://help.dottoro.com/ljlpvjmd.php 
isSameNode : http://help.dottoro.com/ljqqqfft.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: `isSameNode` is deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.isSameNode and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649321/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-two-dom-elements-are-equal