# jQuery - how to check if two elements are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass an element to a function and then match that specific element while traversing parent. The catch (for someone clueless like me) is that this element doesn't have an id. In the following example, I want every element to turn pink except the one clicked on that should turn yellow

```
function colorize(element) {
    element.parent().find('span').each(function() {
        if ($(this)===element) { // the problem is this is always false
            $(this).css('background','yellow');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background','pink');
        }
    });
}
$('span').click(function() {
    colorize($(this));
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441135/how-to-compare-two-doms-or-dom-nodes-in-general

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Comparing JQuery objects will never return true, because each JQuery object is a a new object, even if their selectors are equal.

To compare elements, you have to check whether the DOM elements are equal:

```
this === element.get(0);
```

Comment: @A-OK I see that `element` is not a DOM element either. Use `this === element.get(0)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Please update your answer, in case someone else needs this. :)

Answer (score 32):

You can use the jQuery [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function. The original answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621817).

```
function colorize(element) {
    element.parent().find('span').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(element) ) {
            $(this).css('background','yellow');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background','pink');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [`isEqualNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.isEqualNode) to check if two elements have the same markup

```
this.isEqualNode(element)
```

Or use [`isSameNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.isSameNode) to check if two elements are the same DOM node

```
this.isSameNode(element)
```

Comment: Note that `a.isEqualNode(b)` is not equivalent to `a == b`. `document.createElement('div').isEqualNode(document.createElement('div'))` is `true` even though the nodes are different elements.

Comment: The documentation you linked to says nothing about `isSameNode` being deprecated.  Why do you say it is?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. You're always applying the special style to one specific element, so color them all, and then change the color of the specific element.

```
function colorize(element) {
    element.parent().find('span').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background','pink');
    });

    element.css('background','yellow');
}
```

The problem with your comparison was that you were comparing two objects (jQuery objects). When comparing objects, unless they're pointing to the same thing, they are considered unequal:

```
var o1 = {};
var o2 = {};
o1 !== o2;
```

You can work around this by removing the jQuery wrapper:

```
function colorize(element) {
    var realElement = element[0];

    element.parent().find('span').each(function() {
        if (this === realElement) {
            $(this).css('background','yellow');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background','pink');
        }
    });
}
```

This way, you're comparing DOM elements to DOM elements, and not apples to oranges or objects to objects.

Comment: True, but it is sort of hackish.

Comment: Thanks, but the example is not the problem, just my illustration of the problem. I do need to check if the element matched by find is the same element passed to the function.

Comment: Updated. Lots of problems go away when you stop using jQuery ;)