# Is there a way to compare jQuery objects while ignoring the HTML attributes' ORDER?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unit-testing

Running the following comparison by using jQuery's "is" function will return **false**, since the DOM elements aren't exactly the same, although visually and functionally they are the same:

```
var $a = $('<div id="test" href="http://www.google.com"></div>');
var $b = $('<div href="http://www.google.com" id="test"></div>');
$a.is($b);//FALSE
```

Using direct comparison of the DOM objects will return false as well.

See Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zqwn/5/

So, is there a way to avoid taking the attributes' order into account when comparing?

(Why am I asking this question: 
I am using these comparisons in cross-browser unit tests in which different browsers change the attributes' order while still functionally creating the same DOM elements.)

Comment: I've had a look around and this seems to be an easier solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19342581/2287470 - e.g. `$a.get(0).isEqualNode($b.get(0))` or `$a[0].isEqualNode($b[0])`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zqwn/7/ - the only issue you might run into is the only IE versions it supports are 9+ (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/mobile.html#t135 & http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t135)

Comment: We are using divs because of a specific edge case with a client that uses a "hybrid" mobile app (native code that wraps a webview) that doesn't support anchor tags correctly.

Comment: @Joe you can find some shims to handle IE8, e.g: http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=lwx59vNbUCh82xE58-VCYaA49Ic&cid=ezeK_iHzygY&s=&fp=69576&mp&projSelected=true#L0   That's  said, your comment should be an answer ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff - thanks but it's all Keen's work from the answer I linked to, I just fit it to this question :) Nice that there's a shim as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need to ignore the attributes' **order**, we can use a jQuery selector as the parameter to the "is" function, and then compare the elements' inner HTML separately.

Using the same example from the question:

```
var $a = $('<div id="test" href="http://www.google.com"></div>');
var $b = $('<div href="http://www.google.com" id="test"></div>');
var selector = 'div#test[href="http://www.google.com"]';
($a.is(selector) == $b.is(selector)) && ($a.html() == $b.html());//TRUE
```

See running example: http://jsfiddle.net/GuQ53/4/

---

**UPDATE**

An easier solution that [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287470/joe) linked to in the comments, which should work in IE9+ and handle child elements as well, is using the native "isEqualNode" function. See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19342581/1785003

Comment: That's still interresting to see how can this be done in jQuery, thx for sharing!