# Comparing a DOM Node wih a DOM Element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having some trouble figuring this problem out. I'm aware that everything in a DOM is a node and that a DOM element is also a node. However, my problem is this: I have a DOM node and a DOM element and I need to compare these to see if they are referring to the same element. Is that even possible? I think there is something fundamentally wrong with my question but can't figure out what it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*I have a DOM node and a DOM element*" - You have two DOM nodes. The Node class is a superset of the Element class.

Comment: hmm if they are bot DOM Nodes then why can't I use isSameNode() method?

Comment: @ama2: So is that your actual issue, that `isSameNode` doesn't work? If so, you should probably post your code, or tell which browser isn't working.

Comment: @ama2 Run this: `x instanceof Node`, to test whether `x` is a DOM node.

Comment: I see what the problem is they are both nodes but isSameNode is deprecated and no longer supported in new browsers instead === is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do an `===` comparison. Since they're both objects, the comparison will be identity based.

```
if (my_node === my_element) {
    // they're the same thing
}
```

Comment: how about == ? if compare two objects whether reference the same object?