# How to compare like "x != a OR b" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logic, conditional-statements

Wondering how to add in js script a three more !== or statements. The following script was provided as a spectacular answer by jsfriend00 but the problem is I made the mistake of not mentioning there's three more textareas unaccounted for. I'm stuck with the javascript on the remaining or !== conditions. In the following script how to take say !== to each of the following var obj?

//VIEW FILE for private networking stream between admin and clientele:

```
 <?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

 <html>
 <title>Chat</title>
 <head>

 <?php echo smiley_js(); ?>

 </head>
 <body>

 <?php echo form_open('controller/function');?>
 Reload chat<?php echo form_submit('reload','reload chat');?>
 <?php echo form_close();?>


 <?php if(isset($user_query)): foreach($user_query->result() as $row):?>

 <p>Created at: <?php echo $row->created_at; ?> </p> 

 <p>Updated at: <?php echo $row->updated_at; ?> </p> 

 <p><label for="update"> <?php echo $username_sess.'&nbsp;said'?>:<span class="optional"></span></label>  

  <textarea name="update" id="update" rows="7" cols="30"><?php echo $row->clt_rep_stream ?></textarea>


  <?php echo form_open('controller/function');?>

  <?php echo form_hidden('user_id',$row->user_id) ?>

  <p><label for="adm_update">reply to client:<span class="optional"></span></label>                                
  <textarea name="adm_update" id="adm_update" rows="7" cols="30"> </textarea>
  <?php echo form_error('adm_update'); ?>
   </p>
   <?php echo form_submit('submit','reply');?>

   <?php echo form_close();?>


   <?php echo form_open('controller/function'); ?>

   <?php echo form_hidden('user_id',$row->user_id) ?>

   <p>Replied at: <?php echo $row->adm_created_at; ?> </p> 

   <p>Updated at: <?php echo $row->adm_updated_at; ?> </p> 

   <p><label for="reupdate"> <?php echo $username_adm_sess.'&nbsp;replied:'?><span class="optional"></span></label>  

   <textarea name="reupdate" id="reupdate" rows="7" cols="30"><?php echo $row->adm_rep_stream ?> </textarea>
   <p>                             
   <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'update reply'); ?>
   </p>

  <?php echo form_close(); ?>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

   <script>
   function autoRefresh(refreshPeriod) {
   var obj = document.getElementById("create"); 
   var obj_two = document.getElementById("update"); 
   var obj_three = document.getElementById("delete"); 
   var obj_four = document.getElementById("reload"); 

   function refreshIfSafe() {
   if (document.activeElement !== obj) { 
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    setTimeout(refreshIfSafe, refreshPeriod);
   }
 }
    setTimeout(refreshIfSafe, refreshPeriod);
 }

   autoRefresh(2 * 1000);

   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
    if(document.activeElement !==(obj || obj_two))
```

I tried the following after Brad's post which partially worked but any update or replies *after the first two* and the following js is rendered null and void which is really confusing:

```
    if(document.activeElement !== obj && document.activeElement !== obj_two)
```

Comment: `obj || obj_two` evaluates to `obj` if it is a truthy-value, or `obj_two` otherwise so the conditional `x !== (obj||obj_two)` can be thought of as `x !== obj_OR_obj_two_but_you_dont_know_which`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each condition is separate.  Treat it as such.

```
(document.activeElement !== obj) && (document.activeElement !== obj_two) && ...
```

You could also do this in a loop if your elements weren't explicitly called out like they are, but I don't know how this would fit in your code, as I don't know what your actual code looks like.

Comment: the answer you provided worked. I tried to check it but got an error message that I couldn't except within 9 minute period.

Comment: I like the idea of the loop but not sure at all how that would be done. The script i posted is at the end of my view file. I'm working in codeigniter; MVC.

Comment: hey brad I made mistake I can't make the code you posted work unless I do the following: (document.activeElement !== obj && document.activeElement !== obj_two)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work:

```
<script>
  function autoRefresh(refreshPeriod) {
    var elementArray = [
      document.getElementById("create"),
      document.getElementById("update"),
      document.getElementById("delete"),
      document.getElementById("reload")
    ];

    function refreshIfSafe() {
      if (elementArray.indexOf(document.activeElement) !== -1) {
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        setTimeout(refreshIfSafe, refreshPeriod);
      }
    }
    setTimeout(refreshIfSafe, refreshPeriod);
  }

  autoRefresh(2 * 1000);
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
  function autoRefresh(refreshPeriod) {
    var elementArray = ["create", "update", "delete", "reload"];    

    function refreshIfSafe() {
      if (document.activeElement && elementArray.indexOf(document.activeElement.id) !== -1) {
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        setTimeout(refreshIfSafe, refreshPeriod);
      }
    }
    setTimeout(refreshIfSafe, refreshPeriod);
  }

  autoRefresh(2 * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: tried both didn't work. However I tried Brad's solution which worked when I did: (document.activeElement !== obj && document.activeElement !== obj_two). Another problem though this worn't only for the first two within my foreach loop. Going to post more code to show example.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>You can try</strike> ... no don't !

```
if(!(document.activeElement in [obj,obj_two])){
    // ...
}
```

<strike>By the way, when comparing objects, you actually compare their references adress in memory ... so '!=' is enough.</strike>

Comment: Nooo. Don't say "references". It's not true. `==` and `===` are well-defined in JavaScript *without* talking about "references" and in fact `!=` is orthogonal to object-identity (or "reference" equality). (The only references in JavaScript are *l-values* like property names on the left-side of an assignment operator.)

Comment: less verbose and so powerfull but so forgotten ^^

Comment: Noo, not "addresses in memory" either. Also that won't work correctly, `in` works with **keys**, and *not values* :(  `"a" in ["a","b"]` is false, while `"a" in {"a":1,"b":1}` is true. For arrays `Array.indexOf` would work here. It uses `==` for the comparssion, but works sensibly because `==` is defined sensibly for DOM elements (that is, they are compared "by object identity").

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649321/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-two-dom-elements-are-equal and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.isSameNode for how to get "value equality" with a DOM node check. (`==` and `===` are *always* "object identity" with two DOM elements, the use of `===` simply prohibits type-coercison should one side not be a DOM element)

Comment: -1 The [in operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7) tests whether an Object has a property with a particular name, it doesn't test values. The expression will almost certainly always return false, and test true. And the part about `address in memory` is junk, `!=` uses the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), it has nothing to do with memory addresses.

Comment: Gotcha ... Thank's for reminding me this ! I've never used in key word to compare objects though : I would deserve the cone of shame lol ...  I wont delete this post since it is a good "bad exemple"  :)